# Computing an Approximate Median ("pseudo median") algorithm

Tags: algorithm, median

I've encountered the following question which I have no idea how to solve.

I'd appreciate some Help:

Let (X, d) be a metric space. Let Y = {x1, . . . , xn} ⊆ X be a set of n points in the metric
space. A point x<sup>∗</sup> ∈ X is a ∆-pseudo-median of Y if there exist at least m indices i1, . . . , im
with m > n/2 such that d(x<sub>i,j</sub> , x<sup>∗</sup>) ≤ ∆ for all j = 1, . . . , m.

Assume that a ∆-pseudo-median x<sup>∗</sup> exists for Y (but is unknown).
Devise an algorithm with running time O(n<sup>2</sup>) that finds an index i ∈ {1..n} such that d(xi, x<sup>∗</sup>) ≤ 4∆.

(Assume that evaluating d(x, y) for x, y ∈ X
takes O(1) time).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, we assume that `n > 0` (although the fact that `n/2 < m <= n` actually implies that `n > 0`).

Suppose there is a `Delta`-median `p` of `Y`. Then consider some `x[i]` which is within `Delta` of `Y`. Then for at least `m` values of `j`, we have `d(x[i], x[j]) <= d(x[i], p) + d(p, x[j]) = 2 Delta`. That is, the `m`th-smallest value of the list `[d(x[i], x[1]), d(x[i], x[2]), ..., d(x[i], x[n])]` must be no more than `2 Delta`.

Define `f(i)` to be the `m`th smallest value of the list `[d(x[i], x[1]), d(x[i], x[2]), ..., d(x[i], x[n])]`. Then the smallest value of `f(i)` is no more than `2 Delta`, since there must be some `x[i]` within `Delta` of `p` and thus having `f(i) <= 2 Delta`.

I claim that the `i` which minimises `f(i)` is within `4 Delta` of the `Delta`-median `p`. For we see that `f(i) <= 2 Delta`. Since `m > n / 2`, there must be some `j` such that `d(x[i], x[j]) <= 2 Delta` and such that `d(x[j], p) <= Delta`. Therefore, we see that `d(x[i], p) <= d(x[i], x[j]) + d(x[j], p) <= 3 Delta <= 4 Delta`.

So all we have to do is compute the `i` which minimises `f(i)`. In order to do this, we just compute all values of `f(i)` and then find the smallest.

Computing `f(i)` for a given `i` involves finding the `m`th smallest element of a list with `n` elements. This can be done in `O(n)` using the [median finding algorithm](https://brilliant.org/wiki/median-finding-algorithm/). So computing all the `f(i)`s will take `O(n^2)`.

Finding the minimal value of `f(i)`, once we know all `n` values of `f(i)`, will take `O(n)`.